# Load an entire application server from SAN

Tags: jboss, san

We have always traditionally used SAN as a backend storage for our databases. But recently our SAN vendor threw in an idea that we can even load our Application Servers (JBoss) directly from SAN. 
I was suprised, but the concept is to install the application server on the SAN LUN and then run it from there. The SAN vendor mentioned about ease of DR replication of AppServer configuration, etc. 
Is this a viable strategy for production systems? What are the risks, drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on most Linux or UNIX. You can even boot your whole system from san, and even mount / from SAN.

The draw back is that your kernel must present LUN at an earlier stage. Which is an easy task in Linux/UNIX. Other than that, money matters.

Answer (score 0):

They might be talking about Boot from SAN. This is possible with both FC SAN Cards, and iSCSI cards, and to a lesser extent iSCSI SW only.

My suggestion is if you pursue this you setup a BOOT volume separate from your data volume from you application. If you leverage and DR or Snapshot technology the biggest issue is what level of consistency you need for you DATA. Does it know how to recover if there is a unclean shutdown, or do you need to script the application to quiesce the data so that it is in a consistent state when it returns. Windows apps that participate in VSS can quiesce via the VSS service tied into the SAN vendor, other apps need to be scripted between the SAN and your Application.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your vendor is talking about 'BOOT FROM SAN'. It is quite a viable strategy. Many Datacentre customers are starting to adapt to this. There are 2 option in SAN loading - FC and iSCSI. Your SAN LUN can be used as a boot partition and all your applications essentially run from there.

FC: Its better to use FC SAN boot, since it has a very higher speed and bandwidth, but requires a SAN network (FC adapters, FC cables, switches).

iSCSI: Its slower still much easier than FC, since you can use your LAN network to carry your SAN traffic.

It really comes down to you choice. Good luck !